# How to configure PCI Express hard ip in Stratix IV?

Tags: ip, intel-fpga, pci-e

I want to use PCI Express for my upcoming project. So before working for my project I want to do some basic exprements with PCI express. I tried PCI Express reference for stratic IV and it was succesful. As a next step I want to either modify the design or to do someting by my own.

PCI Express hard ip is there in stratix IV, how I can configure it to do some basic experiment (simplest)?